# Could not find a method onClick(View)

Tags: java, android, xml, togglebutton

I have 2 java files and one toggle button when i click on toggle button i get the error

```
09-17 00:36:24.706: E/AndroidRuntime(30978): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-17 00:36:24.706: E/AndroidRuntime(30978): Process: com.soheil.prolight, PID: 30978
09-17 00:36:24.706: E/AndroidRuntime(30978): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a    method onClick(View) in the activity class com.soheil.prolight.MainActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.ToggleButton with id 'ToggleButton01'
```

i declared toggle in my second java file which is this

```
public class StrobeLightConfig extends Activity {


StrobeRunner runner;
Thread bw;

public final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

public final Runnable mShowToastRunnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        showMessage();
    }
};

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final ToggleButton togglebutton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.ToggleButton01);

    runner = StrobeRunner.getInstance();
    runner.controller = this;




    togglebutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on clicks
            if (togglebutton.isChecked()) {
                //test
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"soli", duration);
                toast.show();
                //test
                bw = new Thread(runner);
                bw.start();
            } else {
                runner.requestStop = true;
            }
        }
    });

    final SeekBar skbar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.SeekBar01);
    skbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {
            runner.delay=progress;

        }
    });

    final SeekBar skbaroff = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.SeekBar02);
    skbaroff.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {
            runner.delayoff=progress;

        }
    });


}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    runner.requestStop=true;
    ToggleButton togglebutton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.ToggleButton01);
    togglebutton.setChecked(false);

    super.onStop();
}

public void showMessage()
{
    String err = runner.errorMessage;
    runner.errorMessage="";
    if(!err.equals(""))
    {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, err, duration);
        toast.show();
    }

    ToggleButton togglebutton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.ToggleButton01);
    togglebutton.setChecked(false);
}
}
```

and my main activity is a  different file i also have have the activity-main xml and onclick vent is declared but none of them work !

```
    <ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/ToggleButton01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/SeekBar01"
    android:layout_marginRight="46dp"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:textOff="@string/powerbuttonoff"
    android:textOn="@string/powerbuttonon" />
```

i just need to run the void but i cant find a way if i remove onclick method in XML error will be gone but nothing happening even the toast i put there to see is the button working or not !

Comment: please post your MainActivity code as that is where the exception is coming from

Comment: this is my class file i want to run the onclick method from my calss file this file is separate .java file @invertigo

Comment: you are going to need to wire the onclick event into the activity that is active (in this case MainActivity). from there, you could call methods on your other class in a variety of fashions.

Answer (score 0):

In your `xml`, you have defined that you want the method `onClick` to be called when the user clicks the item. However, you did not create that method! In your `MainActivity`, add the following method:

```
public void onClick(View v){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply implement the View.OnclickListener interface, and then add the corresponding method:

public void onClick(View v){
     //Your code..`enter code here`
}